# How to avoid erasing the grid line color(default light gray) of excel sheet after changing the background of a cell in C#, ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

My sample code to change the cell color is this. range refers to a cell range.

`range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);`

If i try to change the cell color back to white. Im using this.

`range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);`

But this erases my cell range grid lines(default color of the lines are grey) and everything becomes white. i.e.only 'range' grid lines becomes white and all other cells have the default excel grid color.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you :). As i wanted to access excel through source code I used  ASP.net. Just educational purpose. Thank you for the information

Comment: Ok, you should use a desktop application to work with Office Automation (console, Windows Forms, or WPF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);The problem is occuring because the interior colour of the range of cells is not actually white (it just appears white). Each cell by default is actually transparent (-4142).

So do this when you want to set it back to "normal":

```
range.Interior.Color = -4142
```

---

**Edit:** Best to use Constants and -4142 is equal to xlNone.

**Anonymous Type**
I don't understand why this doesn't work for you? Can you please refine your question? I tried the following and it worked just fine..

```
const Int32 transparent_Color = -4142;
//Set Yellow
var Rng = ActiveSheet.Range["D5:E7"];
Rng.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);

//Set transparent (gridlines come back, so long as you haven't got other code that is interacting with your cells)
var Rng = ActiveSheet.Range["D5:E7"];
Rng.Interior.Color = transparent_Color;
```

Comment: Setting background color of the cell as you said works fine. Thanks a lot. But setting that to the cell border doesn't give any result.
I changed the color to yellow first, then tried to apply -4142 to the cells to show grid lines of each cell. But it doesn't work. Can u suggest any way

Comment: @Jeremy xlNone gives error. there is no keyword to be found

Comment: @Jeremy const xlJezza As BigInt = MEGA_LOAD

Comment: @Jeremy come on man i thought everyone has Jon Skeet level rainbow tables in their head that can instantly lookup the underlying value of number, no matter how big.

Comment: I did the same. And it works.
My problem is when i set yellow, the grid lines disappear. Is it because the transparent color gets hidden  in yellow? or is it actually being erased?

Comment: Your first comment is correct. The gridline is hidden. The grey gridlines are "behind" every other object (at bottom of spreadsheet UI stack). When transparent a cell allows u to see gridline. When made ANY other colour it disappears as it is now blocked from view.

Comment: You could also consider playing with the borderAround method, or the Borders property...
rng.BorderAround(XlLineStyle.xlContinuous,xlThin,xlColorIndexAutomatic, RGB(255,255,255))
Where the above will render a solid BLACK border. If you want the "light grey" border, figure out the RGB or constant for that, and plug it in. Note: This is a hack/workaround... as soon as you go back to transparent you'll now have additional grey border formatting which may/may not be desirable.

Comment: TBH i don't understand your scenario. As best practise i always leave data as is (with appropriate cleansing logic) and leave report formatting to a seperate sheet, or as automation that is done temporarily or seperately to the datasheet.

Comment: okii...now i get it. You answered my question at the first place. I was confusing my self with the grid lines, default color and other colors. Thanx a lot

Comment: @Nathi nw mate, have a great weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Trick: Open Excel > Developer Toolbar > Record Macro > select/highlight range > change backcolor to yellow > change backcolor to white. Now set the **Style to Normal**.

Stop the Macro from recording.

Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>  to go into VBA Editor and look at the code in Module 1.

Simply convert that code to C# - it is almost the exact same Object Model in C# as it is with VB.

Comment: I tried. But I'm confused to use macro as i have no idea about it. But in C# source code I used the property 'Normal'. It sets the whole cell to default. That means the value in it disappears as well.

Comment: not `white` but `xlNone` which is -4142 and it appears transparent